# Unable to use HTTP with php image on Kubernetes

Tags: php, apache, docker, kubernetes

I'm currently in the process of dockerizing a Laravel app and integrating it with Kubernetes. I'm not well-versed in php, so I could be missing something obvious. I managed to access the app with http through the browser running it via docker.

But for some reason whenever I access it through my Kubernetes cluster, regardless of if I type the URL manually, it redirects me to the https version of the URL. And this throws several `Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '<URL>'` errors.

I've tried configuring Apache to use self-signed SSL, but I was unable to get it to work, and the cluster does seem to work on http with Angular apps anyway.

My Dockerfile, Kubernetes config files and apache.conf files look like this:

*(Note that I removed env values for security and brevity)*

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
ENV APP_ENV=prod
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite
COPY ./apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

WORKDIR /var/www/html/my-app
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git zip unzip
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer
RUN /bin/composer install
```

**apache.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    DocumentRoot ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /my-app "/var/www/html/my-app/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/my-app">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**k8s config files**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: in-check
        image: registry-url:5000/my-app
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-cluster-ip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - port: 8082
    targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /my-app/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: my-app-cluster-ip
              servicePort: 8082
```

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Any and all help is appreciated.

***Update: it seems to load properly using http on my EKS cluster, but still results in the above errors on my copy of minikube.***

*Edit: [here's the link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml) to the Ingress controller config I'm using.*

Comment: Maybe because your service is using `targetPort: 443`? Try to set it as `targetPort: 80`, and you should land on the non-SLL port of Apache.

Comment: Oops, that's a mistake. It is actually set to 80 in my current set up. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Which redirect code are you getting when accessing via `http` for the first time? Did you check if you have any [HSTS](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/) configured for the address/host that you are trying to access? (it implies your browser enforcing the SSL on the client side).

Comment: How do I check the redirect code I receive? When I navigate to `http` it automatically redirects me to `https` and loads the HTML. However, none of the scripts and/or CSS loads. I followed the instructions in the article you sent, and the minikube IP isn't listed under the HSTS set for Chrome.

Comment: You can open the DevTools on your browser before accessing (`F12` on Chrome/Firefox), then go to `Network` Tab, check the `Preserve Log` and access your application. The redirect should be the first entry. The [Mixed Content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content) is because of your application is calling other resources using `http`. You need to either solve the redirect problem or change your code to call the external resources (scripts, CSS, etc) also using `https`.

Comment: I understand the mixed content errors. I'll have to try calling the full URLs instead of relative paths to see if that works. When I looked at the status codes I received a `308 Permanent Redirect`, but I'll have to see if the `Preserve Log` has more detailed info tomorrow.

Comment: that's your ingress controller probably. what's the configuration of the ingress controller nginx server?

Comment: I'm just using the default `nginx-ingress-contoller` from the installation. It's too lengthy to include in my question, so I've added the link to the configs I installed from. The controller is at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

So I was unable to get the app to run on `HTTP` on my local copy of minikube, but after @Eduardo Baitello's advice, I changed all the resources' relative paths to full URLs with the `HTTPS` protocol included.

This isn't ideal since if the domain name or IP changes I have to manually update all resource URLs, but this is the only workaround I can find right now.